# Gulp resolve failed

Tags: gulp, babeljs

When I run my command:

```
gulp build
```

I get the error:

```
[13:28:52] Requiring external module babel-register
node_modules/nan
resolve failed for "caniuse-db": Error: Cannot find module 'caniuse-db'
resolve failed for "babel-runtime": Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime'
```

This seems to happen after I changed my preset in my `.babelrc` from `es2015` to `es2015-loose`.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktraces on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/developit/preact-boilerplate/issues/88) seem very similar to yours... They resolved the issue by switching from the `es2015-loose` preset to the `es2015` preset with the `loose` option:

```
["es2015", { "loose": true }]
```

Comment: When I do that, I get another error: `ReferenceError: [BABEL] gulpfile.babel.js: Using removed Babel 5 option: base.loose - Specify the `loose` option for the relevant plugin you are using or use a preset that sets the option.`